# When the acceleration is a function of speed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

Sometimes we see that the acceleration is expressed as a function of speed, for example, an air friction model:
$$a=-kv\mp g$$ and the direction of speed is considered the positive direction.

I find that the speed determines the acceleration as shown above, however the acceleration also controls the speed. In this way, neither speed nor acceleration can be solved.

We may consider the differential equation or something similar but it is apparently not feasible when we really solve problems.

What are common approaches to solving such kinematic problems?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @josephh I want to know what are common approaches to solving such kinematic problems, and I’ve edited the question to include it.

Comment: Yes, we may consider the differential equation and this is easily "feasible when we really solve problems". I recommend you either study some basic mechanics and differential equation (you won't need too much) or ask a more specific question.

Comment: And I think it is not right to call this a "kinematic problem". Kinematics is about describing motion without considering the forces that act. The equation you show, however, stems from Newton's $F=ma$, when supplying it with an ansatz for the force given by gravity plus linear (Newton) drag. This is thus not solely about kinematics, but dynamics. ;)

Comment: @kricheli I was thinking that these problems don’t focus on why they move and what forces there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that acceleration is time derivative of velocity, and (if you need) velocity is time derivative of position

$v = \dot x$
$a = \dot v = \ddot a$

the equation of your question can be written as a simple first-order linear ordinary differential equation,

$\dot v + k v = g$

whose solution reads

$v(t) = \dfrac{g}{k} + A e^{-kt}$.

Prodivded the initial condition $v(0) = v_0$, it's possible to determine the constant $A$,

$A = v_0 - \dfrac{g}{k}$

to get the solution of the problem as

$v(t) = \dfrac{g}{k} \left( 1 - e^{-kt}\right) + v_0 e^{-kt} $.

From this expression, you can see that starting from the velocity $v(0) = v_0$, the system exponentially approaches the limit velocity $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} v(t) = \frac{g}{k}$, for which the air drag equilibrates the gravity force.

### Solution of first order linear ODE

You can find the solution of the non-homogeneous linear first-order linear ODE,

$\dot y + a y = f(t)$

as the sum (linear problem $\rightarrow$ principle of superposition holds) of a solution of the homogeneous equation $y_o(t)$ and a particular solution $y_1(t)$ of the non-homogeneous equation.

**Solution of the homogeneous equation.** The solution of the linear equation

$\dot y + k y = 0$,

using the property of the exponential $(e^{Ct})' = A e^{Ct}$. If you look for a solution with the form $y(t) = A e^{Ct}$ and put it into the homogeneous ODE, you find

$0 = ACe^{Ct} + k Ae^{Ct} = A(C+k)e^{Ct}$,

and thus $C = -k$, and $y_o(t) = A e^{-kt}$.

**Particular solution of the non-homogeneous ODE.** This really depends of the forcing. For a constant forcing $f(t) = g$ a particular solution is a constant solution $y_p(t) = K$ s.t. $y_p'(t) = 0$. Putting it into the non-homogeneous equation, you get

$0 + k K = g$

and thus $y_p(t) = K = \frac{g}{k}$.

**Solution.** The solution of the ODE thus reads

$y(t) = y_o(t) + y_1(t) = A e^{-k t} + \dfrac{g}{k}$.

Now, and only now, you can prescribe the initial condition to find the value of constant $A$.

Comment: How could we solve differential equation? Is it just like observe and guess its expression then solve for some undetermined coefficients?

Comment: What's your proficiency in Math? The solution of first-order linear ODE is one of the simplest one, for which you can find a solution in a closed form. I'm editing my answer, with few details. Anyway, you can find many references on the web.

Comment: @youthdoo:  Here in the US, the question "how do we solve a differential equation?" is usually the subject of a semester-long undergraduate mathematics course.

Comment: Is the answer sufficiently clear? Anyway, here in Italy, you do something about ODEs (linear 1st and 2nd order) in the last years at the high school, if you're lucky to have such a good professor: you find the solution without any theorem about uniqueness and existence, and apply ODEs in formulating and solving simple problems in Physics, usually mechanics and electrical circuits. Then you do it at the first year of BSc: for sure if you do Math, Physics, Engineering